# Is it possible to make a generic Jersey CRUD Class?

Tags: java, generics, jersey, crud

I've been using the Jersey Framework and had a question.

Is it possible to create a generic class that could handle CRUD methods for any entity? The reason being is that it would be nice to have one class that can handle the CRUD stuff and just extend it for new entities that are added.

From what I can tell the biggest hurdle is the `@Path` only being able to take a constant for the value. I did some experimenting and notice I can only pass variables that are final to the `@Path` annotation.

Is there something that I am missing here or is this a limitation of the framework?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this again, we didn't find a generic way to do it but we found a way that minimizes the code. In a super class we have a generic class with something like:

```
protected Response add(T t) {
...
}
```

Which has all the logic and returns the Response object. In the child class all we have to do to extend it is:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response add(MyContact contact) {
    return super.add(contact);
}
```

You can even use a `@Path` annotation here if you want to customize the URL. Minimizes the code to easily extend it but I don't think we can go any more generic than that. Hope this helps!